# Giving View permission to Databricks jobs using CLI or API

Tags: permissions, databricks, acl, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I am creating a Databricks job using CLI.  Is it possible to give View permission to my job to another user using Databricks CLI or API?  If so, please provide details on how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't have option to provide job access control via Databricks CLI or REST APIs.

By default, all users can create and modify jobs unless an administrator enables jobs access control. With jobs access control, individual permissions determine a user’s abilities. This [article](https://docs.databricks.com/security/access-control/jobs-acl.html) describes the individual permissions and how to enable and configure jobs access control.